# Use plot function to generate scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

Could you help me with the following question?

I would like to generate a scatter plot using `plot` function, where the `x-axis` would be columns DR01_PV to DR06_PV and the `y-axis` would be column D1. Both of the PV variable

```
library(dplyr)

data <- structure(
  list(Id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
       date1 = c("2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20",
                 "2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20",
                 "2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20",
                 "2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-04-02",
                 "2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03",
                 "2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-08",
                 "2021-04-09","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-04-10"),
       Week= c("Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday",
               "Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Thursday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday"),
       DTPE = c("Ho","Ho","Ho","Ho","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","Ho","Ho"),
       D1 = c(8,1,9,3,5,4,7,6,3,8,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3), DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,7,3),
       DR02 = c(8,1,4,3,3,4,1,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3), DR03 = c(7,5,4,3,3,4,1,5,3,3,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),
       DR04= c(4,5,6,7,3,2,7,4,2,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),DR05 = c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),
       DR06 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))


data<-data %>%
  group_by(date2) %>%
  select(D1:DR06) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)

x<-subset(data, select = DR01:DR06)

x<-cbind(data, setNames(data$D1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))

PV<-select(x, date2, D1, ends_with("PV"))

PV
       date2 D1 DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV DR04_PV DR05_PV DR06_PV
1 2021-04-02 33       7       9      14      14      12       5
2 2021-04-03 22       0       0       0       0      -1      -1
3 2021-04-08 12       0       0       0       0       0       0
4 2021-04-09  8       0       0       0       0       0       0
5 2021-04-10  5      -5       0      -2      -2      -2      -2
6 2021-07-01 21       9       5       2      -1       0       6
```

Answer (score 1):

I made plot with every `DR0...`'s are in one plot. If not, please let me know.

```
PV %>%
  select(- date2) %>%
  reshape2::melt(.,id.vars = "D1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, D1, group = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Could you use the plot function instead of ggplot?

Answer (score 0):

either make a facet:

```
lvl = grep("_PV",colnames(PV),value=TRUE)

par(mfrow=c(1,6))
for(i in lvl){
   plot(PV[[i]],PV[["D1"]],xlab=i,ylab="D1")
}
```

[image]

you need to pivot your data long:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

PV_long = PV %>% 
select(D1:DR06_PV) %>% 
pivot_longer(-D1) %>%
plot(D1 ~ value,col=factor(name,levels=lvl),data=.)
legend("topleft",fill=palette(),lvl,cex=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: StupidWolf, thanks for reply! The x-axis you consider is D1?

Comment: oh right, the y axis should be D1, let me correct it